# Extract a TypeScript method in Visual Studio Code

Tags: typescript, refactoring, visual-studio-code

Is there a possibility to extract a method with a shortcut in Visual Studio Code when writing TypeScript?

```
function printOwing() {
  printBanner();

  // Print details
  console.log("name:  " + name);
  console.log("amount " + amount);
}
```

So that with one shortcut I could extract the `printDetails()`:

```
function printOwing() {
  printBanner();
  printDetails();
}

function printDetails() {
  console.log("name:  " + name);
  console.log("amount " + amount);
}
```

Similar to Eclipse → right click → *Refactor* → *Extract method…*.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Extract method and extract function were added in Visual Studio Code 1.16: *[JavaScript and TypeScript refactorings](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_16#_javascript-and-typescript-refactorings)*

To use them, select a block of code and then either click on the lightbulb or use the `editor.action.quickFix` action (<kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>) to view the list of refactorings.

You can also setup a [keybinding for extract method](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/refactoring#_keybindings-for-code-actions):

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+r ctrl+e",
  "command": "editor.action.codeAction",
  "args": {
    "kind": "refactor.extract.function"
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't tell you why it can't extract a method. Which for some reason is most of the time I want to do so :-(

Comment: Please file issues for cases where it doesn't show up as expected

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Code doesn't ship with a default shortcut to extract methods in a TypeScript file (although it does look like it is [supported in C# files](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v0_7_0)).

You might be able to find an extension with this capability on the [marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/), but I was not able to.

The "refactorix" and "JS Refactorings" extensions have an extract variable, but no extract method. So close!